# Changing embed autostart, OnClick

Tags: php, javascript, embed

Currently, I have an embed source that autostarts by default, and is hidden.
I needt a control via an  Tag to stop the embed from playing without removing "?ID=(number) from the URL.

My thoughts are to disable autostart and reload the page somehow.

I know that it's not possible to change an embed's properties and have it work with JQuery (at least last I knew), so it would probably mean looking for a way to use javascript to refresh the page and change the autostart property somehow (don't know how), but maybe there's a more efficient way to do it, anyhow?

Another idea I had was to include the embed source in a hidden IFrame, and just change the source of the IFrame when  link is hit, so no queries are needed, but would that be more or less effecient?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some looking around for a few more hours, and I decided to place the embed in a div tag, then used

```
<SCRIPT>function pStop() {document.getElementById('playstat').innerHTML = '';}
```

Worked like a charm. :)